# How do I look up a nested array by key value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've got a JS array of jobs I want to use to pump data into a handlebars template depending on which job users click.

```
var data = { jobs: [
   {jobName:"ACME", jobRole: "Vice President", jobDesc: "..."},
   {jobName:"Square Co", jobRole: "Director", jobDesc: "..."},
   {jobName:"Compu Mega Net", jobRole: "Manager", jobDesc: "..."}
]};
```

I've got a set of  elements that each have a data attribute that matches the jobName to be displayed.

```
<a href="#" class="job" data-jobName="ACME">
<a href="#" class="job" data-jobName="Square Co">
<a href="#" class="job" data-jobName="Compu Mega Net">
```

The question is: how do I look up the appropriate object in my array that matches the jobName selected by the user?

I've tried utilizing `$.inArray("ACME", data);` and `$.inArray("ACME", data.jobs);` but am always getting back `-1` (not found).

Comment: $.inArray doesn't work on objects, hence the name inArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will produce an Array:

```
var matchingJobs = data.jobs.filter(function(job){ return job.jobName == "ACME" });
```

You can pull the last matching job from it like this:

```
var firstMatch = matchingJobs.pop();
```

Comment: Thanks for this, @joeytwiddle. I'm curious, when you write `data.jobs.filter(function(job){ return job.jobName ...`, what is the `job` parameter? I notice @MrCode has a similar looking function utilzing `obj` as the same parameter. Just trying to understand the solution.

Comment: We are giving an anonymous function to the filter function.  The filter function calls our function once for each item in the list, passing the item as the first parameter.  Our function receives the item, naming the first parameter `job`, and then returns true or false to indicate whether the filter should keep it.  We could equally have chosen a different name for that parameter, such as `obj`.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has [`$.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) which can do the search. For example, if you know the target object will always be present, you can do:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var search = $(this).data('jobname');
    var result = $.grep(data.jobs, function(obj){ return obj.jobName == search; })[0];
    console.log(result); // the target object
});
```

If you're not sure if the object will be present, then you need to check the return value, instead of directly accessing the first element:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var search = $(this).data('jobname');
    var resultArray = $.grep(data.jobs, function(obj){ return obj.jobName == search; });

    if(resultArray.length > 0){
        console.log( resultArray[0] ); // the target object
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ObjectSelected(jobName_selected) { 
    var  appropriate_object = null; 

    var data = { jobs: [
       {jobName:"ACME", jobRole: "Vice President", jobDesc: "..."},
       {jobName:"Square Co", jobRole: "Director", jobDesc: "..."},
       {jobName:"Compu Mega Net", jobRole: "Manager", jobDesc: "..."}
    ]};

    for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++)
        if(data[i].jobName = jobName_selected)
            appropriate_object = data[i];
}
```